# what are the implications of a singleton implementation in a multi-server environment?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton, clr

what are the implications of a singleton implementation in a multi-server environment?  Is the scope of a singleton limited to the CLR of a single machine or is there any way to configure a multi-server environment to use a singleton implementation?  Or are other techniques used to achieve the goals of a singleton implementation in a multi-server environment?

Comment: Singletons are an anti-pattern that make your code unnecessarily hard to test. Spread across multiple servers, you'll have a near-impossible-to-test mess on your hands. Use IoC instead.

Comment: is .net caching a better alternative to singletons?  it can be easily delegated to it's own cache server and ensures a single instance.  that being said, does the .net use the singleton pattern in its caching framework at all?